# SSAS Cube process data save in every hour

Tags: ssas, cube

I have SSAS cube, which process data in every hour, like 10 AM, 11 AM, 12 PM, 13 etc. Now if someone please give me solution, how can I see the processed data details/data snapshot of 10AM, at 12 PM? I mean if the time is 12PM now, and I if I want to check, what was my processed data at 10AM, then how can I check that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if someone plz reply, is it possible to save a cube in each hour and show the data (hourly) in excel according to date?

Comment: Probably it's not the processing requirement... I don't think you can see different hours data in cube without modification your data in DW... If you want to see what new data each hour is inserted, just insert in your databse column with time type (and update it each time you insert your data), connect dimension time and you will see each hour data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you would need different cube instances, or archive the data via reports run automatically. As soon as the cube processing finishes successfully, all previous versions of the cube are overwritten.

You could either copy the cube before you process it, e. g. via backup and restore, which can be automated. Or you could archive some reports. E. g. produce some reports from the cube with whichever tool you use for Analysis/Reporting, and archive these.

How many old copies you keep and when you start throwing them away or overwriting is very much dependent on the business requirements. One approach could be to keep the hourly data for 24 hours (i. e. 24 copies), and one daily copy for the last month (i. e. 28 to 31 copies), and after a month to keep only one weekly or one monthly copy.